# Detect a click and compare URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to detect mouse clicks after page loads and the function is exectued which deletes ads.

After the mouse click is detected, it will compare the URLs and it should do this on every mouse click.

I have tried using Google's stuff, but couldn't figure out, so I switched to plain JS.

```
    let host = window.location.host; // www.adjaranet.com
    let path = window.location.pathname; // /...
    let href = window.location.href; // http

    // alert(path); // movie section = /Movie/main // homepage = /

    if (href == "https://www.adjaranet.com/") {

      function deletor() {
        // some code that executes...
      }

      deletor();

      // Here I want to detect mouse clicks and then compare the URLs
    }
```

And if mouse is clicked and the page is changed (url), it should run another separate function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() { // after page has loaded

    function onMouseClick(event) {
        // check url
        if (window.location.href === 'https://www.adjaranet.com/') {
            // your code here
        }
    }

    // register event listener so onMouseClick is called whenever a click happens         
    document.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will listen to page clicks:

```
document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  console.log("Clicked!") // whatever function you want to run here
})
```

Put this in a TamperMonkey script (or something similar) to get it to run automatically when you hit certain pages.

In terms of actually deleting ads though, it's as simple as finding the element on the page and either removing it or doing something like changing its innerHTML to `""`. Make sure you handle cases where the element isn't there in the first place though, otherwise you might get a bunch of console warnings/errors.